# (Centered) Automatic Numbering of Figures

Tags: stylesheet

I want to create a figure caption cell style that prefixes a **centred** figure caption with Figure X, where X is an incremental number

I have seen two methods for automatically numbering figures:

Method 1: Use a CellDingbat to place the label in the left margin of the notebook

```
Cell[StyleData["FigureCaptionLeft"],
 CellDingbat->Cell[
   TextData[{"Figure ", 
     CounterBox["FigureCaptionNumbered"], "."}]],
 TextAlignment->Left,
 CounterIncrements->"FigureCaptionNumbered",
 CellMargins->{{115,0},{0,0}},
 MenuSortingValue->10000]
```

Method 2: Use CellFrameLabels to place the label above, below, left or right of the cell frame. Using this method I have not been able to obtain cell frame label and the caption on the same line.

```
Cell[StyleData["FigureCaptionCentred"],
 CellMargins->{{65, 0}, {0, 0}},
 CellHorizontalScrolling->True,
 CellFrameLabels->{{None, None}, {None, 
    Cell[
     TextData[{"FIGURE ", 
       CounterBox["FigureCaptionNumbered"], "."}]]}},
 CellFrameLabelMargins->{{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
 TextAlignment->Center,
 CounterIncrements->"FigureCaptionNumbered"]
```

The image should illustrate the captions created from the described styles and my desired caption
[image: Screenshot of the two methods and my desired caption]

Any ideas on how to create a style which prefixes centred text with a automatically generated number (with the number and text on the same line)?

Comment: If you intend to enter a new cell, separate to your graphic/plot output cell then you don't need to stick the number in a cell frame.

Answer (score 3):

I have used this style:

```
Cell[StyleData["FigureCaption"],
 CellMargins->{{54, 24}, {10, -5}},
 TextAlignment->Center,
 LineSpacing->{1, 2},
 ParagraphSpacing->{0, 5},
 LanguageCategory->"NaturalLanguage",
 ScriptLevel->1,
 CounterIncrements->"FigureCaption",
 FontFamily->"Times New Roman",
 FontSize->12]
```

To give me this:

[image]

Explanation:

You appear to be using a new cell for figure captions. So to get the first line underneath the plot (incidentally I made the plot align to centre) I entered a new cell and made it FigureCaption style. The typed everything bar the number, and then you just need to go to the main menu and choose **Insert > Automatic Numbering ...** and then choose `FigureCaption` as your counter. The subsequent two cells were simply cut and pastes of the initial entry. You can see that the counter automatically updates.

**Edit**

This code creates a button for pasting a new figure caption cell

```
DisplayForm[
 ButtonBox[
  StyleBox[RowBox[{"Figure Caption", " ", " cell"}], 
   FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontWeight -> "Bold"],
  Active -> True,
  ButtonFunction :> 
   CompoundExpression[
    NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
     Cell[TextData[{StyleBox["Fig. ", FontWeight -> "Bold"], 
        StyleBox[CounterBox["FigureCaption"], FontWeight -> "Bold"], 
        "   "}], "FigureCaption"]]],
  ButtonData :> {"\[ThinSpace]", "Text"}]]
```

Here is the result of repeatedly pressing the button:

[image]

Select the cell with the button in it and then from the menu **Palettes > Generate Palette from Selection** will create a palette for you and **Palettes > Install Palette** will make it accessible for you whenever you want it.

Comment: That works, however I did want the process more automated by the style.  Do you recommend an alternative method for labeling figures with the figure and the caption in the one cell?

Comment: Off the top of my head I do not know of a why to do this via stylesheets because those methods employ cell frames and you have already ruled them out. If you want it automated use a palette. See edit