# CellDynamicExpression is too sensitive in V11

Tags: bugs, front-end, options, cells

**Bug introduced in V11.0.0 and fixed in 11.1**

---

```
CellPrint @  Cell[ 
   BoxData @ ToBoxes @ InputField[Dynamic@var], 
   "Output", 
   CellDynamicExpression :> Refresh[Print[RandomReal[]], None]
]
```

[image]
It triggers printing on each keystroke, which was not the case in V10.

It is `InputField` independent. Evaluate this and try to edit the same cell later:

```
SetOptions[
  EvaluationCell[], 
  CellDynamicExpression :> Refresh[Print[RandomReal[]], None]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to remove this topic from unaswered stack, the bug was reported

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3718333] was created.
>
> [...] I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided. [...]

and fixed in V11.1