# Is it possible to Include predefined text in a custom stylesheet?

Tags: stylesheet, style

I added the following code to my private stylesheet for a notebook.  Now when I create a new cell in that notebook with the style "Theorem", all of the options below are pre-populated for that cell.

Is it possible to include things other than options in the code below?  Can I include predefined text in a style?  For example, can I create a style that populates the first line in the cell to always read "Hello World"?  It would save me a lot of time If I could this in the stylesheet, rather than outside of it.

```
Cell[StyleData["Theorem"],
CellFrame->0.5`,
CellMargins->{{30,10},{7,7}},
CellFrameColor->RGBColor[0, 0.67, 0],
LineSpacing->{1,3},
ParagraphSpacing->{0,6},
TabSpacings->3,
CounterIncrements->{"Theorem"},
FontSize->14,
Background->RGBColor[0.88, 1., 0.88]]
```

Comment: Already asked, unfortunately no answers yet: [Styles that prepend text to cell contents](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124791/5478)

Comment: Ok, now there is an answer, does it fit your needs?

Comment: Yes! This works great!