# Modify CellLabel of Print cell in stylesheet

Tags: customization, cells, stylesheet

I would like to modify the style of `Print` in a Mathematica notebook. Locally, I can do so by toggling on `Show Cell Expression` of some output of `Print` (i.e. in some cell generated by the command), adding `ShowCellLabel->True` and modifying `CellLabel->"mylabel"`.

This works for a single cell and I would like to make this change for all cells of the notebook. Hence I edit the Stylesheet and paste the section `Local definition for Style "Print"` from `Default.nb` -> `Core.nb` to the private style definition of the notebook.

If I now modify this particular style (editing the cell expression in the style definitions), I can e.g. successfully change the margins of all `Print` cells in the notebook. I can also toggle on the labels using `ShowCellLabel->True`, but I can NOT modify these labels. Any command `CellLabel->"mylabel"` is simply ignored in the notebook. Instead, the label `During evaluation of In[.]:=` remains.

How can I change the cell label using the stylesheet s.t. it applies to all `Print` cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print inserts the label explicitly in a Cell that is about to be printed so there is not much you can do about it.

1. You can create your own Print like here: [How to Print to the Console](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5735/5478)
2. Or you can set a `CellDynamicExpression` for a `"Print"` style that will modify the `CellLabel` and remove itself just after. Similarly to: [Styles that prepend text to cell contents](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129021/5478)

Let me know if you have troubles adapting any of those solutions.