# How to make a StyleSheet with certain text in some cell types like Subsection, Subsubsection and alike?

Tags: stylesheet, education

I am modifying several StyleSheets to adapt them to convenient use at school. Now I am working on the StyleSheet for Mathematics classes. I would like to make several types of default headings on the level of Subsections and Subsubsections. I would like to make them in such a way that upon opening such a Cell it opens already with a certain title. For example "Homework". In addition it would be nice, if it is possible to evaluate `DateString[]` there.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you want `DateString[]` to be evaluated when the cell is created? Dynamically updated? Neither seems convenient to the way I imagine using the stylesheet to create documents, but what do you have in mind?

Comment: Something like `CellDingbat->"Section", CellMargins->{{120, Inherited}, {8, 18}}`?

Comment: @ Michael E2 I had in mind that as soon as one makes a cell with such a style one gets the text: "Homework 23.10.12". So the `DateString[]` I would like to be evaluated once as soon as the cell is first time created. Further, another cell appears with the text: "Exercise Nr." so that the student only needs to enter the number of the exercise.

Comment: You can adapt [this: 129021](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129021/5478) to whatever fits your need, right? Also related: [189164](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/189164/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Thank you. Most part of my aims I achieved with that. Now I would like also to develop a cell style which will evaluate `DateString[]` as soon as such a style is addressed from Menu.  I tried this `Cell[StyleData["DateString"],
"Input",
 CellDingbat->BoxData[ToBoxes[DateString[]]],
FontSize->16,
 MenuSortingValue->10000]` and several other variations, but no of them worked. Could you think of something like that?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch how about `CellDynamicExpression :> Refresh[SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellDingbat -> ...]; (*and drop CellDynamicExpression*),None]`

Comment: @Kuba Thank you. I made it as follows and it seems to work: `Cell[StyleData["Klassenarbeit"],
 CellDynamicExpression:>SetOptions[
   EvaluationCell[], CellDingbat ->TextData[{StyleBox["          Klassenarbeit    ", 
   FontColor -> RGBColor[0.7, 0, 0], FontSize -> 40], 
   StyleBox[DateString[{"Day", ".", "Month", ".", "Year"}],
   FontSize -> 24, FontSlant->"Italic", FontColor -> RGBColor[0., 0, 0]]}]],
 ShowGroupOpener->True,
 TextAlignment->Left,
 MenuSortingValue->1480,
 FontFamily->"Helvetica",
 FontSize->30,
 FontWeight->"Plain",
 FontSlant->"Plain",
 Magnification->1.5]`